# How to read special characters like \n from XML file in Java?

Tags: java, xml

In my XML I have

> <'nodeName'>separator=\n <'/nodeName'>

I am using DOM Parser to parse the XML. When I read the Value in Java Code, I am getting the value as **\n**. It is not treated as line break but instead a Character(\n).

I am very new to XML Parsing and so I am not sure that what has to be done to get the value as **line break** instead of a character **\n**

Adding few lines from my code. Sorry I cannot add complete code but I hope my question is clear and below lines of code can add some extra light to it.

```
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(file);                
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
XPathExpression xPExprAdditionalInfo = xPath.compile("./nodeName");
String separator =  xPExprAdditionalInfo.evaluate(node);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Place your code so we can see how you are reading the `.xml` file.

Comment: Have you tried `.replace("\","\\")` before printing the line?

Comment: The character `\n` **is** a line break. Put it in a String, print it and see.

Answer (score 1):

I hope below explanation clears your confusion:

Escape sequence `\n` is not new line character in `XML` file. This is just a way how Java understands new lines.

New line character depends on under laying operating system. Find more detailed explanation [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).

I think there are two solutions

1 . So for your problem you can try to replace the `\n` characters with new line escape sequence.

```
separator.replaceAll("\\\\n", "\n");
```

1. Have new lines in you `XML` if you have liberty to do so

   ```
   <'nodeName'>separator=
    <'/nodeName'>
   ```